# Run time error getting while Installing sqlite

Tags: sqlite

when i am trying to install **sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x64-2010-1.0.74.0** then getting error "failed to install microsoft visual c++ run time"? My system is 64 bit.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) package from Programs and Features for me to fix this issue.  The bundle then reinstalled the necessary component.

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved this issue. I was getting this error while installing the sqlite , failed to install Microsoft visual c++ run time. It was a problem of C++ which gets install while installing Visual Studio 2010 or any version so **I just again ran the Visual Studios 2010 and selected an option for repair.** After repairing i restarted my computer and again tried to install , it got install without any error.